# CRenderFunction is not working correctly in coreui-free-vue-admin-template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, core-ui

I am using  the `coreui-free-vue-admin-template` for one project.[image]

The above image is the screenshot of `_nav.js`
The icon of the first item is displayed correctly but others are not displayed

[image]

If you know the right way to use this template, please give me your advice.
This is `TheSidebar.vue`.

```
<template>
    <CSidebar 
    fixed 
    :minimize="minimize"
    :show="show"
    @update:show="(value) => $store.commit('set', ['sidebarShow', value])"
    >
    <CSidebarBrand class="d-md-down-none" to="/">
        <CIcon 
        class="c-sidebar-brand-full" 
        name="logo" 
        size="custom-size" 
        :height="35" 
        viewBox="0 0 556 134"
       />
      <CIcon 
        class="c-sidebar-brand-minimized" 
        name="logo" 
        size="custom-size" 
        :height="35" 
        viewBox="0 0 110 134"
      />
    </CSidebarBrand>

    <CRenderFunction flat :content-to-render="$options.nav"/>
    <CSidebarMinimizer
      class="d-md-down-none"
      @click.native="$store.commit('set', ['sidebarMinimize', !minimize])"
    />
   </CSidebar>
</template>

<script>
import nav from './_nav'

export default {
  name: 'TheSidebar',
  nav,
  computed: {
    show () {
      return this.$store.state.sidebarShow 
    },
    minimize () {
      return this.$store.state.sidebarMinimize 
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

CRenderFunction is working correctly.

You need to modify the following file: /src/assets/icons/icons.js

[file ubication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UMTS.png)

Import the icon you want to use:
[Import example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18ZzP.png)

And finally, add it to 'iconsSet'

[Adding to 'iconsSet'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5D7pX.png)